# Which areas in CS will be (or have been) most affected by fully homomorphic cryptography?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm in the middle of planning a 5000ish word essay on fully homomorphic cryptography, the current practical implementations and their limitations.

Which areas of CS as a subject have been (or will be) most affected or will utilise fully homomorphic cryptography the most in the coming years and developments?

Comment: What research have you already done?  We expect you to do some research on your own before asking here.  (And, by the way, a bit of friendly advice: do your own homework.  There's a reason your instructors assign you homework: because it will help you learn!)

Answer (score 2):

None.  No area of CS has been affected by fully homomorphic encryption yet, because it isn't practical (yet).  If it becomes practical, it could have a significant effect on computer security and cryptography, but that remains speculative at this point.

Read [my answer to *“What is the most practical fully homomorphic cryptosystem?”*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/628/351) for more details.

Comment: Hmm, so I would want to focus moreso on homomorphic cryptography and perhaps at the end touch on the possibilities of fully homomorphic cryptography?

Comment: @c3ntury, a great first step would be to do some reading on these topics.  That will likely give you a much better sense of how to focus your essay.  Start by searching for "homomorphic" on this site and on Wikipedia and on Google; you'll find some good information and some pointers to where to learn more, and that ought to give you a reasonable overview, for starters.